# Как получить доступ к ресурсам в AndroidLibrary project

Tags: java, android, android-resources

У меня есть обычный `Android` проект, к которому дополнительным модулем подключен другой `AndroidLibrary` проект. В `AndroidLibrary` в папке **res/layout** лежит `.xml` с версткой и я хочу получить этот ресурс из основного модуля проекта. Пробую через файл ресурсов достучаться но этого файла просто нету и мне предлагает его создать, т.е. я не могу достучаться ни с главного модуля, ни с либы.

Пробую сделать так:

```
com.myLibrary.R.layout.list_item
```

выдает ошибку:

> Error:(41, 100) error: package com.myLibrary.R does not exist

Comment: R.layout.list_item так пробовали?

Comment: Подсвечивает красным и предлагает сделать импорт с из пакета основного  модуля.

Comment: `к которому дополнительным модулем подключен другой AndroidLibrary проект` - как подключен?

Comment: через Project Structure/ Modules / Dependencies / add module dependencie ( Java классы видит а вот ресурсы почему то нет)

Comment: т.е. даже в самой библиотеке я не могу к ресурсам достучаться

Comment: м.б. `Build`->`MakeModule`, что бы `R`-класс сгенерился

Comment: @ermak0ff теперь появился, спс!

Comment: @ermak0ff можете запостить ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте **Make** модуля, что бы сгенерировался **R.class**

`Build`->`MakeModule`